# RegEx a RegEx match

Tags: .net, regex, c#-4.0

I'm having trouble building the correct regex for my string. What I want to do is get all entities from my string; they start and end with `'`. The entities are identifiable by an amount of numbers and a `#` in front. However, entities (in this case a phone number starting with `#`) that don't start or end with `'` should not be matched at all.

I hope someone can help me, or at least tell me that what I want to do isn't possible in one regex. Thanks :)

**String:**

`'Blaa lablalbl balbla balb lbal '#39'blaaaaaaaa'#39' ('#39#226#8218#172#39') blaaaaaaaa #7478347878347834 blaaaa blaaaa'`

**RegEx:**

`'[#[0-9]+]*'`

**Wanted matches:**

- `'#39'`
- `'#39'`
- `'#39'`
- `'#226'`
- `'#8218'`
- `'#172'`
- `'#39'`

**Found matches:**

- `'#39'`
- `'#39'`
- `'#39#226#8218#172#39'` <- **Needs to be split(if possible in the same RegEx)**

**Another RegEx:**

`#[0-9]+`

**Found matches:**

- `'#39'`
- `'#39'`
- `'#39'`
- `'#226'`
- `'#8218'`
- `'#172'`
- `'#39'`
- `'#7478347878347834'` <- **Should not be here :(**

**Language:**
C# .NET (4.0)

Comment: @ApoY2k Because it's not *directly* surrounded by `'` character, I guess. Possibly (probably?) wrong, though.

Comment: #7478347878347834 is not allowed because it is part of the string and thus not an entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can use lookbehind/lookaheads and that your regexp supports variable length lookbehinds (JGSoft / .NET only)

```
(?<='[#0-9]*)#\d+(?=[#0-9]*')
```

Should work... Tested it [using this site](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) and got these results:

```
   1. #39
   2. #39
   3. #39
   4. #226
   5. #8218
   6. #172
   7. #39
```

Breaking it down is pretty simple:

```
(?<=        # Start positive lookbehind group - assure that the text before the cursor
            # matches the following pattern: 
  '         # Match the literal '
  [#0-9]*   # Matches #, 0-9, zero or more times
)           # End lookbehind...
#\d+        # Match literal #, followed by one or more digits
(?=         # Start lookahead -- Ensures text after cursor matches (without advancing)
  [#0-9]*   # Allow #, 0-9, zero or more times
  '         # Match a literal '
)
```

So, this pattern will match `#\d+` if the text before it is `'[#0-9]*` and the text after is `[#0-9]*'`

Comment: Wow, that works perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Could you explain what this does exactly? Thanks alot :)

Comment: @Willy - Honestly though -- I voted for @Jan's answer.. It is WAY easier to understand what you are doing there...

Comment: You are correct sir. It IS alot easier to understand, but I wanted to do it in one RegEx if possible, which is what your method does :). Which method would be faster and better performance wise?

Comment: @Willy - It's hard to say which method will perform better (especially since I don't have a .NET compiler), you should setup some sort of profiling testing to see...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this in one regex, you'll need two:

First take all matches that are between single quotes:

```
'[\d#]+'
```

Then over all those matches, do this:

```
#\d+
```

---

So you'll end up with something like (in C#):

```
foreach(var m in Regex.Matches(inputString, @"'[\d#]+'"))
{
    foreach(var m2 in Regex.Matches(m.Value, @"#\d+"))
    {
          yield return m2.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Too bad that it isn't possible in one RegEx, guess this'll have to do. Thanks for typing it out for me aswell ;)

Comment: Gnarf posted an answer that does it in one RegEx, thank though!

Answer (score 1):

As you don't specify a language, here is a solution in perl :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $s = qq!Blaa lablalbl balbla balb lbal '#39'blaaaaaaaa'#39' ('#39#226#8218#172#39') blaaaaaaaa #7478347878347834 blaaaa blaaaa!;

my @n = $s =~ /(?<=['#\d])(#\d+)(?=[#'\d])/g;

print Dumper(\@n);
```

Output :

```
$VAR1 = [
          '#39',
          '#39',
          '#39',
          '#226',
          '#8218',
          '#172',
          '#39'
        ];
```

Comment: I had no idea that RegEx was language specific, the RegEx bit works universally right? This does the trick aswell, #\d+(?=#|'). Thanks! Your RegEx is alot shorter then the one Gnarf posted, what are the differences?

Comment: His only tests that the character following the match is a `#` or `'` -- and not all regular expressions can handle lookahead, lookbehind, etc.  If you put a `#` after `#7478347878347834` in your test string, it would then match that as well...

Comment: @gnarf: Yes, you're right, i've updated the regex, adding a lookbehind of fix length because variable length lookaround isn't allowed in perl and in some other languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can match this with `#\d{1,4}\b` (Tested on https://regexr.com/)

```
#        | Matches '#'
\d{1,4}  | Matches 1 to 4 digits
\b       | Matches a word boundary position between a word character and non-word character or position (start / end of string)
```

As the matches are all followed by non-word characters, this picks up all the wanted matches, but does not match `'#7478347878347834'` as it is too long.